# group by in Matlab to find the value that resulted minimum similar to SQL

Tags: sql, matlab, group-by

I have a dataset having columns a, b, c and d
I want to group the dataset by a,b and find c such that d is minimum for each group
I can do "group by" using 'grpstats" as :

grpstats(M,[M(:,1) M(:,2)  ],{'min'});

I don't know how to find the value of M(:,3) that resulted the min in d

In SQL I suppose we use nested queries for that and use the primary keys. How can I solve it in Matlab?

Here is an example:

```
>> M =[4,1,7,0.3;
2,1,8,0.4;
2,1,9,0.2;
4,2,1,0.2;
2,2,2,0.6;
4,2,3,0.1;
4,3,5,0.8;
5,3,6,0.2;
4,3,4,0.5;]

>> grpstats(M,[M(:,1) M(:,2)],'min')
ans =

2.0000    1.0000    8.0000    0.2000
2.0000    2.0000    2.0000    0.6000
4.0000    1.0000    7.0000    0.3000
4.0000    2.0000    1.0000    0.1000
4.0000    3.0000    4.0000    0.5000
5.0000    3.0000    6.0000    0.2000
```

But M(1,3) and M(4,3) are wrong. The correct answer that I am looking for is:

```
2.0000    1.0000    9.0000    0.2000
2.0000    2.0000    2.0000    0.6000
4.0000    1.0000    7.0000    0.3000
4.0000    2.0000    3.0000    0.1000
4.0000    3.0000    4.0000    0.5000
5.0000    3.0000    6.0000    0.2000
```

To conclude, I don't want the minimum of third column; but I want it's values corresponding to minimum in 4th column

Comment: Can you show (brief) sample data, the output you are getting? Not sure I understand your question. What do you mean by "the value of M(:,3) that resulted the min in d"?

Comment: sure. I edited the question contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`grpstats` won't do this, and MATLAB doesn't make it as easy as you might hope.

Sometimes brute force is best, even if it doesn't feel like great MATLAB style:

```
[b,m,n]=unique(M(:,1:2),'rows');
for i =1:numel(m)
    idx=find(n==i);
    [~,subidx] = min(M(idx,4));
    a(i,:) = M(idx(subidx),3:4);
end

>> [b,a]
ans =
        2            1            9          0.2
        2            2            2          0.6
        4            1            7          0.3
        4            2            3          0.1
        4            3            4          0.5
        5            3            6          0.2
```

Comment: Thanks this works. I was thinking about doing it with loops but was trying to do it in a more efficient way.

Comment: well this is a sample dataset; the real one is way bigger. thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

I believe that

```
temp = grpstats(M(:, [1 2 4 3]),[M(:,1) M(:,2) ],{'min'});
result = temp(:, [1 2 4 3]);
```

would do what you require. If it doesn't, please explain in the comments and we can figure it out...

If I understand the documentation correctly, even

```
temp = grpstats(M(:, [1 2 4 3]), [1 2], {'min'});
result = temp(:, [1 2 4 3]);
```

should work (giving column numbers rather than full contents of columns)... Can't test right now, so can't vouch for that.

Comment: No, both return the same wrong answer. If you run either of them in Matlab you will see for the row M(:,[1 2])=[2 1] which is the first row of the answer, it returns M(:,3)=8. while if you look at the initial dataset, the value of M(:,[1 2 4])=0.2 corresponds to M(:,3)=9 and not 8. It is not preserving the initial rows and it does find the minimum of 3rd and 4th column separately. I just need the minimum of 4th columns and the corresponding value in 3rd column.

Comment: I will have to try this in the morning when I have access to Matlab to test some alternatives... sorry I can't do this now.

Comment: if the 'min' in grpstats(M(:, [1 2 4 3]), [1 2], {'min'}) would return the indices instead of values, then it would be easier to solve the problem.