# How can grpstat return indices instead of values?

Tags: matlab

I am using grpstats to find minimum of one column based on grouping of two other columns.
For more detail about the problem see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18605141/group-by-in-matlab-to-find-the-value-that-resulted-minimum-similar-to-sql)
The function looks something like this:

```
grpstats(M,[M(:,1) M(:,2)],'min')
```

how can it return the indices instead of value of minimums?

Comment: See my answer to your other question. Voting to close this as duplicate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [group by in Matlab to find the value that resulted minimum similar to SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18605141/group-by-in-matlab-to-find-the-value-that-resulted-minimum-similar-to-sql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`grpstats` simply can't return the indices instead of values. You have to program an equivalent function to get the indices of interest just like @Sam Roberts did [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18605141/group-by-in-matlab-to-find-the-value-that-resulted-minimum-similar-to-sql) with `unique` and `find` matlab's functions.